# How to create portable code (.net standard 2.0) for a Raspberry Pi 3 using Windows 10 IoT (UWP)?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, .net-standard-2.0

I want to port an app to run on the Raspberry Pi 3.

For the app I think I am forced to use UWP, but I don´t want to use UWP libraries. I think it is a good idea to use .NET Standard 2.0 libraries.

My questions:

- Is this the right way to get a portable code base?
- Will UWP App with .net standard 2.0 libraries work?
- Do .net standard 2.0 libraries support *normal* (non-UWP) unit tests?

Comment: [This article](http://krzyskowk.postach.io/post/unit-tests-in-uwp) shows how to use NUnit with UWP. Add `NUnit Templates for Visual Studio` and create a `NUnit 3 Test Project (Universal Windows)` project

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Many thanks - this looks very promising.

Comment: .Net Standard 2.0 apps only work with UWP with the Windows 10 Fall Creators update, which is not released yet. Currently UWP support .Net Standard 1.4. But yes, .Net Standard is the way for portable code in .Net going forward.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake: Thank you, I would like to mark this as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now as the fall creators update is available I solved this task like follows:

- App / Entry point is an UWP application
- DLL / Libraries are .net standard 2.0
- unit tests are created with 'add new xunit'
- IoC is done with CompositionRoot pattern using AutoFac container (also .net standard dll)

Everything is working now so far. 
For sourcecode visit https://github.com/thosch1800/TT4-to-Garmin

Answer (score 0):

> - Is this the right way to get a portable code base?

Yes, you can create a .net standard library as a reference for your UWP project. Moreover, considering portable in windows 10 platform scope, Windows Runtime components is a better choice, the advantage is that it can support any language, including C#, Visual Basic, JavaScript, and C++.

> - Will UWP App with .net standard 2.0 libraries work?

Currently UWP support .net Standard 1.4. Please reference here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard .

UWP support .NET Standard 2.0 is work in progress and will ship later this year.

> - Do .net standard 2.0 libraries support normal (non-UWP) unit tests?

Yes, it supports unit test of Unit Test Project or NUnit 3 Test Project

> - Has someone experience with such a configuration?

When creating a unit test project for UWP library project, it indeed forces to create an Unit Test App(Universal Windows). I tried to create a NUnit 3 Test Project (Universal Windows), there was an exception such as "**Unspecified error(Exception from HRESULT:0x80004005(E_FAL))**". Please reference here to get more information: http://krzyskowk.postach.io/post/unit-tests-in-uwp.

Comment: why WinRT is the better alternative? I thought it was the win8 way and is replaced by the .net core/.net standard?

Comment: @TomSchardt [Windows Runtime Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/) is a new thing - essentially UWP components. They are *NOT* portable though, unless by "portable" one means "runs only on Windows 10". Everyone else though should use .NET Standard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for making this point clear. When talking about portable I think of running on e.g. Windows 10 and Linux...